# Make a list of Boolean Function Output to check if all are True

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to check if multiple Boolean results of a function can be converted to a Boolean list.

A function loops through a list and produces the following output:

```
True
False
False
```

or

```
True
True
True
```

I would like to create a function to check if all are True and return False if not (not all true).
I tried the `all()` function but received the following errors:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this solution

**Code:**

```
list_to_be_checked=[1,1,2,3]
results=[]
def test(t):
    for i in t:
        if i == 1:
            results.append(True)
        else:
            results.append(False)
def check(my_list):
    if all(my_list):
        return True # all elements in my_list are True
    return False  # else return False

test(list_to_be_checked)
print(check(results))
```

**Output:**

```
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a list with all your boolean values and then take advantage of the fact that a `True` boolean variable has a numeric value of 1 and a `False` of 0. So in a list where all elements are `True`, the sum of the list must be equal to its length:

```
my_list = [True, True, False, True]
print(sum(my_list)==len(my_list))
```

This will output `False`, because `sum(my_list)` evaluates to 3 and `len(my_list)` to 4.